# Elasticsearch : "birthday" exception

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my document:

```
{
  "user" : {
    "name" : "test",
    "birthday" : "123"
  }
}
```

when I post this to elasticsearch , it went wrong:

```
"type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason" : "object mapping for [user.birthday] tried to parse field [birthday] as object, but found a concrete value"
```

But if I changed it to this:

```
{
  "user" : {
    "name" : "test",
    "birthay" : "123"
  }
}
```

It went well.

Is the `birthday` a keyword ? What can I do for it ?

Comment: I suspect you have predefined mappings, and `birthday` simply doesn't fit there. Add your mappings.

Comment: You forgot the "d" in your mapping.

Comment: You are right , it has different type with other data . Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with your mapping. I suppose your birthday is a date, like below:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "birthday": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your mapping looks something like this:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "birthday": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties" : {
                "date" : {"type" : "string"}
            }
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

Or at least something similar that sets the birthday field to be an object type. Your mapping actually needs to be as follows:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "birthday": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "YYYY-MM-dd",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

And the reason that setting the document field name to 'birthay' instead of 'birthday' worked is that if you don't have a type mapping set for a field Elasticsearch tries to determine one that fits best dynamically.

It's also worth noting that if you don't have a mapping defined and you're getting this error it might be because a document you're indexing before the document that fails has something other than a string format date as the birthday. Thsi would cause ES to determine the field type as something else and then fail on other documents.